# Flutter File Read Write Permission Android Version 13

Tags: android, flutter, file

How can I write file in Flutter abive android 33 phone. I need to get the permission for write. Now , its show only denied.

I want to know how to ask to get permission for file read write with flutter for above android 13 phones

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler Use this package.

Comment: I'm using this package bro. It works under android version 13 , but not works on Android 13 and above.

Comment: I'm using it for notifications and it works for Android 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions have been marked deprecated and have been fully removed/ disabled since Android SDK 33 (Android 13).

If your application needs access to media files Google recommends using the `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES`, `READ_MEDIA_VIDEOS` or `READ_MEDIA_AUDIO` permissions instead Read and Write permission. To request these permissions make sure the compileSdkVersion in the android/app/build.gradle file is set to 33.